# Tomcat starts only with Midnight commander

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I have a really weard situation here :-)

The plan is to have Tomcat 9 with CentOS running as a service.
I followed some guidelines like [this here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7) from DigitalOcean.

Tomcat didn't start as a service. I only got an empty log file "catalina.out".

Okay, let's start Tomcat in the shell. I ran "./startup.sh" (Which is "./catalina.sh start") as root. I got the return from the script:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Tomcat started.
```

Looks good, but it isn't true, Tomcat was not started. Again, i got an empty log file.

Next, i tried "./catalina.sh run" and Tomcat started in the actual window. It looked very good. My configuration from "setenv.sh" was working and the Web UI was working too.

Later on i executed "./startup.sh" with Midnight Commander by mistake and Tomcat started!

I'm a bit confused, what happens here :-)
The facts:

- Tomcat starts with "./catalina.sh run"
- Tomcat starts with "./startup.sh" executed by Midnight Commander
- Tomcat does not start with "./catalina.sh start" or "./startup.sh"

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: May i ask again for help? Do i need post more details of this issue?

Cheers!